# Probability & Forecasts

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling

I am doing a forecast on turnover and would like to know how i can work out the probability that the next sales figure will be over a certain amount given that we have all the data from previous years. How is this possible?
e.g. 
Year 1 100
Year 2 110
Year 3 125
Year 4 145
Year 5 170
Year 6 209
Year 7 245
Year 8 286
Year 9 354
Year 10 452

What is the probability that Year 11 will for example exceed 540? How do I work this out?

Comment: any ideas, however vague, are welcome

Comment: You will need some additional input. Currently you gave us 10 numbers in a sequence and ask us to predict the 11th one. Humans are good at pattern matching, but whatever "probability" you derive based only on those 10 numbers can be no better than random guessing. What is the model you are using for sales growth?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Willie Wong that you will need to make some assumptions to get a probability, some models will be more "assumption heavy" than others. If you have enough data to assume a particular model for your sales (e.g., linear trend with normally distributed errors) then you will be able to get a more precise estimate.

However, if you simply assume that your past sales growth is representative of sales growth in the near future, then you can get a rough probability estimate by using the following nonparametric approach:

1. Calculate the difference between each squential pair of the N successive annual revenues (e.g., $T_2-T_1$), you will get N-1 differences (i.e., $d_i$).
2. Assign a probability of $\frac{1}{N-1}$ to each difference (this assumes that the early data is as relevant as later data, hence the equal weighting of each difference).
3. Calculate N-1 future revenue predictions by adding each difference to the last known annual revenue: $Prediction_i=T_N+d_i$.
4. The resulting probability mass distribution will be an approximation of the distribution of possible future revenue in period $T_{N+1}$ You can use this approximate distribution to get coarse probability estimates for questions like the one you posed. However, this will be dependent on the truth of the assumptions underlying the model.

You may not like the discreteness and coarseness of the results, but without further knowledge of the details of the process, which would suggest a more precise model, you really can't expect to be able to express your uncertainty with much precision either...you get out what you are able to put in...statistics cannot generate knowledge from ignorance.